# JPA in SE Application: How to exchange EntityManager within application's lifecycle

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am writing a small database driven application which uses Hibernate as JPA-Provider. I am fairly new to Java though I have choosen that as a study project.

I do hope that anybody can lead me the right track of how to use the EntityManager throughout the application's lifecycle. In reference to the Hibernate manual (2.4. Obtaining an EntityManager in a Java SE environment) ..."An entity manager factory is typically create at application initialization time and closed at application end." That's understood.

As per my understanding in the Preloader of my JavaFX I should create the EntityManager since it will take a few seconds for the initialization.

I used that code for it.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("h2")
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

But how can I the share that EntityManager throughout my application?

What's the best practice for that?

thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't share the EntityManager because it's not thread safe.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/. in reference to the manual it says..."For those who are familiar with Hibernate, an entity manager factory is very much like a session factory. Actually, an entity manager factory is a wrapper on top of a session factory. Calls to the entityManagerFactory are thread safe."

Comment: entityManagerFactory is Thread safe BUT EntityManager is NOT thread safe.

Comment: ok. thanks for the clarification! Though what is the best practice to work with the EntityManagerFactory and the EntityManager? Should I instantiate the EntityManagerfactory at application start up only? Thanks

Comment: Yes you should create the EntityManagerFactory at startup and then use this to create EntityManager when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an instance of EntityManagerFactory once, better a singleton instance ([singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) and use it in your application. But you have to create EntityManager every time, if you need an EntityManager instance in your services or repositories.

For Java desktop applications you can create a JpaUtil static methods like below and use the JpaUtil in services or repositories for data access.

```
package com.cemikta.customersfx.util;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * JPA util
 *
 * @see EntityManagerFactory
 * @see EntityManager
 *
 * @author Cem Ikta
 */
public class JpaUtil {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JpaUtil.class);
    private final static String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "customersFxPU";
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    private JpaUtil() {}

    /**
     * Create entity manager factory as singleton instance.
     *
     * @return entity manager factory from persistence unit
     */
    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        logger.debug("get entity manager factory for persistence unit {}", PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
        if (emf == null) {
            synchronized (EntityManagerFactory.class) {
                if (emf == null) {
                    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
                }
            }
        }
        return emf;
    }

    /**
     * Close the entity manager factory.
     */
    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        logger.debug("close entity manager factory for persistence unit {}", PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
        if (emf != null) {
            emf.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets new entity manager instance.
     *
     * @return new entity manager instance
     */
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        logger.debug("get entity manager for persistence unit {}", PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
        return getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

Check my [AbstractService](https://bitbucket.org/devsniper/customersfx/src/master/src/main/java/com/cemikta/customersfx/service/AbstractService.java) implementation in JavaFX MVC application demo source code if you need sample JPA implementations.

Comment: Vielen Dank, Cam, awesome. Da kommt fuer mich als Anfaenger noch einiges auf mich zu!

Comment: There is another conceptual question which popped up in my mind. How do I handle a required login to get access to the the application? Shall I use therefore a JDBC call? or what would the best approach for that, many thanks.

Comment: @Marko please write a new question in stackoverflow.